# trip_cost('Pittsburgh', 5) raised an error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python

Here is my code, which said "trip_cost('Pittsburgh', 5) raised an error: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'" when I ran it. 
Find the original question here: https://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-P5YtY/1/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096
I could not find the typo or other kind of bugs...HELP! Thanks.

```
def hotel_cost(days):
    return 140 * days
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    if city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    if city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    if city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    rental_car_cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        return 40 * days - 50
    elif days >= 3 and days < 7:
        return 40 * days - 20
    else:
        return 40 * days
def trip_cost(city,days):
    return rental_car_cost(days)+hotel_cost(days)+plane_ride_cost(days)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ...+plane_ride_cost(days)
> ```

I think you mean `city` there. And write something so that the bottom can't fall out of the function again.